# How to download file into data/data/com.****.*** folder and open it

Tags: android

I need to download some pdf files into data/data/com.****.*** folder.

Those files are application specific and only application should read and display it that's the reason storing on data/data/com.****.*** folder.

Please let me know how to download into that folder and open/read it in the application.

I know how to download it into SD card, but I do not have idea to downloading to application specific folder.

Please let me know some code examples to do this and also I need to know the capacity/size of the data/data/com.****.*** folder.

Comment: If you know how to download to SD card then you can do that too to your app specific directory in internal memory. All code is exactly the same. So I don't understand why you ask for the obvious. You only have to change a path.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you want write your own applications Data folder, you can create a FileOutputStream like this `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.**.*/somefile");` than use that output stream to save file. Using the same way you can create a `FileInputStream` and read the file after.

You will get Permission Denied if you try to access another application's data folder.

I am not sure for capacity but you can calculate the size of the data folder using this

```
File dataFolder = new File("/data/data/com.**.*/");
long size = folderSize(dataFolder);

...

public static long folderSize(File directory) {
    long length = 0;
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile())
            length += file.length();
        else 
            lengthlong += folderSize(file);
    } 
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> To Write file

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/your_package_name/file_name.xyz");
```

> To Read file

```
FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(new File("/data/data/your_package_name/file_name.xyz"));
```

Now you have your input stream , you can convert it in your file according to the file type .
I am giving you example if your file is contain `String` data the we can do something like below ,

```
 BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String mDataRow = "";
            String mBuffer = "";
            while ((mDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                mBuffer += mDataRow + "\n";
            }
```

Remember to add write file permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```